# Lawful intercept in freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I am trying to implement Legal intercept in Freeswitch.I am using conference application to implement LI.but following issues that i cant solve

1.Called party should be connected only After interceptor call connected.cuz I dont miss 183 from called party that part also interceptor need to hear.here i dont know how to control LI using conference application.  DTMF could be useful.but i cant use DTMF in LI implementation.

2.Then ,if caller/callee send BYE to callee/caller,callee/caller and  interceptor must be closed.I cant succeed with "endconf" for both caller and callee

please suggest me!! can i succeed LI with conference application?? is there any way to implement LI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using eavesdrop instead of the conference:
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+eavesdrop